# using Poppler Qt4 c++

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, poppler

i need a pdf viewer library to be used in my app,
am using c++ and QT

i downloaded [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)
and code example [The Poppler Qt4 interface library](http://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt4/)
but, i do not know how to configure the library to work in my code.
i am using QT Creater, in windows xp.

thanks in advance, any hint is appreciated as am completely lost.

Comment: i edited the `code`. #include <poppler-qt4.h>`code`. with the correct path of the header file.
currently i have this error in QT creator ":: error: cannot find -lpoppler-qt4".

Answer (score 5):

assuming you've installed poppler headers and libraries on your system correctly. I'm on ubuntu, and running:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

made poppler libraries built and installed. From my understanding you can use **msys/mingw** on windows to something similar to this.

Now in your `.pro` file add following lines:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /path_to_poppler_include_files/qt4
LIBS += -L/path_to_poppler_libs -lpoppler-qt4
```

and the code like this:

```
#include <poppler-qt4.h>

....

QString filename;

Poppler::Document* document = Poppler::Document::load(filename);
if (!document || document->isLocked())
{
    // ... 
    delete document;
}
```

should build and run for you.

hope this helps, regards