# Project ERROR: poppler-qt5 development package not found for mac

Tags: macos, qt, poppler

I have Qt 5.5 installed and poppler 0.36 installed on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.However when I was trying to build a .pro project, it shows error message like this:

```
Project ERROR: poppler-qt5 development package not found
```

I've tried with adding

```
INCLUDEPATH += /opt/local/include/poppler/qt5
LIBS += -L/opt/local/lib -lpoppler
```

to .pro file, but it doesn't look like working.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: maybe `-lpoppler-qt5` instead of `-lpoppler`? (found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135353/using-poppler-qt4-c) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857303/exploiting-poppler-in-qt-creator-help))

Comment: no, i've tried that also

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently in the same boat as you.  From what I understand, the Qt5.5.0 pkg-config files are broken, and poppler depends on those build files to build it's poppler-qt5 bindings.  [Word on the street](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/44150#issuecomment-141722083) is that perhaps Qt5.5.1 ([coming out this week probably](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.releasing/day=20150924)) will resolve this.

Comment: _"perhaps Qt5.5.1 will resolve this"_ <--- for me it did

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error when compiling  [qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview) in Ubuntu. I solved this by installing `libpoppler-qt5-dev` library (see it [here](https://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt5/)). This also installed `libpoppler-dev`.